# Fused multiply-add in Racket

Tags: racket, ieee-754

Is is it possible to use [fused multiply-add](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply%E2%80%93accumulate_operation) in Racket?

I'm attempting to port some numerical code that relies on the single rounding of the fused operation, but after several searches haven't found any way to use `fma` or similar in Racket.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it from the C library using the [FFI](https://docs.racket-lang.org/foreign/index.html):

```
(require ffi/unsafe ffi/unsafe/define)
(define-ffi-definer define-libc #f)
(define-libc fma (_fun _double _double _double -> _double))
(fma 3.0 2.0 1.0)
;; => 7.0
```

That works for me on Linux. On Windows you may need to give a different library to [`define-ffi-definer`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/foreign/Defining_Bindings.html#%28form._%28%28lib._ffi%2Funsafe%2Fdefine..rkt%29._define-ffi-definer%29%29).

You can also use `_double*` instead of `_double` for the arguments to automatically convert Racket's other numeric types to doubles.

If the performance is critical, you may need compiler and/or runtime support to avoid the overhead the FFI imposes. In that case, you might want to ask on the [Racket Users mailing list](https://lists.racket-lang.org/).

Comment: Technically, `fma` is defined in `libm`. But it seems Racket already has `libm` preloaded (I checked by running `ldd /usr/bin/racket`), which is why you were able to use it without having to explicitly load it.

Comment: This is perfect for my use!  Thanks a ton :)